# -webkit-overflow-scrolling breaks absolute positioning

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, absolute, mobile-webkit

I am building a page that needs to have some elements which stick to the top of the page when they would otherwise be scrolled off the screen. I managed to do this using `position:absolute`. Everything was working perfectly, but it needed momentum scrolling. I added `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch` to the css of the scrollable area. This broke everything. My sticky elements with `position:absolute` are now just scrolling with the rest of the content.

My question is this:

Why does `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch` affect absolute positioning, and is there a way around this?

UPDATE: I added an alert whenever a child element becomes "fixed" or "unfixed". The alerts continue to fire, so the styling is still being applied, it just isn't working. This means that it's not a problem with keeping track of scroll position but rather a problem with the styling.

UPDATE: I tried using `position: fixed` instead of `position: absolute` and `-webkit-overflow-scrolling` broke that too

UPDATE: After a lot of digging, I found references to this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18163568/native-like-momentum-scrolling-on-body-in-ios-webapp) and [here](http://blog.dsetia.com/2013/04/16/jquery-mobile-fixed-position-and-momentum-scrolling.html). However, the only proposed solution in both cases is to restructure the DOM so that the sticky elements are not in the scrollable area. This is a difficult thing to do in my case, and I would prefer not to have to. Have things progressed since ios5 or is that still the only option?

Comment: This appears to still be an issue in iOS 10

Answer (score 0):

On the last question - yes the issue is present in ios5. Extracting the absolute positioning element outside of the scrollable area worked fine for me.

Comment: thank you @user3222482 but as I mentioned above, that is not an options for me, so does not solve my problem :(