# Absolute positioned elements not fixed in scrollable list

Tags: html, css, scroll

I have a long horizontal list like

```
<ol>
    <li>A</li>
    ...
</ol>
```

The `ol` has `overflow-x: scroll` and the `li`s have `display: inline`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/0qh5af23/6/)

Also, the first and last element have `position: absolute` and are sticky at the begin/end of the list and are always visible.

Now, when you open this in mobile safari/chrome (I have a iPhone 6 with iOS9) you'll see that the scrolling does work but without momentum. So I added

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/0qh5af23/7/)

to the `ol` css. Now you can scroll with momentum, but the sticky elements are not sticky any anymore. This doesn't make any sense to me, any suggestions how to fix this ?

UPDATE: Found a useful link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27320728/webkit-overflow-scrolling-breaks-absolute-positioning).